# How To Manage Routing in Single Page website Angular 9

Tags: angular, routes, angular9

i have a single page website created by angular and i need to create routing between components same page

this is `routing.module`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent },
  { path: 'work', component: WorkComponent }

];
```

and next is `navbar.Component`

```
  <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{'home' |translate}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/about']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{'about' |translate}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/services']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{'ourServices' |translate}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/work']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{'ourWork' |translate}}</a>
                        </li>
```

and next is `app.component.html`

````
<app-headder-video [contact]="contact"></app-headder-video>
<app-about></app-about>
<app-services></app-services>
<app-work></app-work>
<app-footer [contact]="contact"></app-footer>```
````

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

add [router-outlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) to the  app.component like this

````
<app-headder-video [contact]="contact"></app-headder-video>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer [contact]="contact"></app-footer>```
````

Comment: I Added Already 
Not Working 
Router Redirect URL but not redirect link to other component in same page (SPA)

Comment: router-outlet allow us to redirect to another component in same page without page reload